# How to declare method reference in groovy?

Tags: java, function, groovy, lambda, method-reference

Im trying to use method reference in groovy. And I could not get it working.

The following is working in groovy.

Option2> `list.stream().map(user -> user.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList())`

What Im trying to achieve?

Option1> `list.stream().map(User::getName).collect(Collectors.toList())`

The above call is giving following error.

```
unexpected token: : @ line 33, column 14.
User::getName
1 error
```

Any suggestions how I can achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `::` shortcut to create a lambda is only supported since Groovy
3.0.  With said version your code there should work just fine.

Yet,
what you want to do there has shortcuts already in Groovy for a very
long time.  You can use the spread operator `*.` and it will give you an
`ArrayList` back.  E.g. `list*.name` is the "groovy" way to write that.

The main difference here is, that this operation is **eager**.  If you
need the lazyness of the Java streams (e.g. because your example is
simplified), then you can always use a Groovy closure instead of
a lambda.  There might be need for a cast, but Groovy usually figures
this things out quite fine.

E.g.: `list.stream().map{ it.name }.collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 2):

You can only use [`Collection::collect`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#collect(java.util.Collection,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) like this:

```
list.collect{it.name}
```

---

You can also specify the collector type, for example if you want to use the equivalent of `.collect(Collectors.toSet())` you can use:

```
list.collect(new HashSet(), {it.name})
```

---

[**Groovy demo**](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/8Ax)

Answer (score 1):

The scenario looks overcomplicated to me.

If you simply want to re-write java's

```
list.stream().map(User::getName).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

into Groovy, you simply get:

```
list*.name
```

or (getter)

```
list*.getName()
```